# Directly make pointer from ints

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

I was learning about shared memory, and I would like to send an address pointed to a struct variable from one process to another.

What I did was writing the variable's address into the shared memory, printing the address, then keeping the process alive with an infinite loop. This process will be called process 1. The code:

```
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    sprintf(ptr, "%p", &temp);
```

After that, I read the address as a char array from another process (process 2), then I casted it to a long int, with this code

```
    sscanf((char*) ptr, "%lx", &intVal);
```

then I directly assign a pointer of said struct with this value:

```
    student* p = intVal;
```

but when I try to access the memory region, it produces a Segmentation Fault, although when I run this line

```
    printf("variable A is at address: %p\n", p);
```

it prints the exact address from process 1.

So why does C give segmentation error even when I keep both processes alive?

Comment: regular addresses in your program dont exist in the other program. If you want to share structs etc you have to place them (not their addresses) in shared memory

Comment: Every process has its own address space.

Comment: @pm100 Oh god yes that is correct. The stupidity of mine... thank you.

Comment: *All* addresses in one userspace process are specific to that process, including, for example, the base address to which a shared-memory segment is mapped.  Just creating a shared memory segment is not enough to share data among processes.  You must also have a way for all the participating processes to map that segment.  There are various ways to do this, but sending a pointer value from one process to another is not one of them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's possible to specify the address that [`mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/mmap.html) or [`shmat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/shmat.html) will use to map the shared memory into a process.  If that address is the same in both processes, a pointer to data in shared memory is valid in both processes.  Selecting a proper address with something like [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) in play can be problematic...

Comment: Sort of, @AndrewHenle.  Yes, if the base address of the shared memory is the same in both processes, then pointers to the same object within will have the same value in those processes. There are means to *request* that, but the system is not certain to be able to fulfill such requests, so it is perilous to rely on it doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), where each process has its own address space.

What's located at one address in one process is completely unrelated to what's located at the same address in a different process. This means one process can't intentionally and accidentally write to memory used by another process. And same goes for reading.

This is great for stability. One misbehaving program doesn't crash the entire machine. This also permits different users with different permissions.